# Необходимо сымитировать сбор сундука в JS консоли

Tags: javascript, массивы

Мне нужно сделать так, что-бы X при сдвиге на ячейку в которой стоит * становился поверх *  и появлялся консоль лог 'Сундук собран'. У меня проблема в том  что я не знаю как мне дать понять JS что X попал именно на ячейку в которой стоит *
`

```
    const rows = 6;
    const cols = 10;
    const moveSet = {
        up: 0,
        down: 1,
        left: 2,
        right: 3,
    };
    let heroPos = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
    };
    let area = [];

    function rndChest(rwcl) {
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * rwcl);
    } // Функция которая генерирует случайную ячейку для сундука

    function render() {
        for (let row in area) {
            console.log(area[row]);
        }

        console.log(' ');
    }

    function setChest(chests) {
        for (let value = 0; value < chests; value++) {
            area[rndChest(rows)][rndChest(cols)] = '*';
        }
    }

    function move(direction) {
        if (direction === moveSet.right && heroPos.y !== 9) {
            area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = ' ';
            heroPos.y += 1;
            area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = 'X';
        } else if (direction === moveSet.right && heroPos.y === 9) {
            console.log('Там стенка');
        } if (direction === moveSet.left && heroPos.y !== 0) {
            area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = ' ';
            heroPos.y -= 1;
            area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = 'X';
        } else if (direction === moveSet.left && heroPos.y === 0) {
            console.log('Там стенка');
        } if (direction === moveSet.down && heroPos.x !== 5) {
            area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = ' ';
            heroPos.x += 1;
            area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = 'X';
        } else if (direction === moveSet.down && heroPos.x === 5) {
            console.log('Там пол')
        } if (direction === moveSet.up && heroPos.x !== 0) {
            area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = ' ';
            heroPos.x -= 1;
            area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = 'X';
        } else if (direction === moveSet.up && heroPos.x === 0) {
            console.log('Там потолок')
        } 
        
        render();
    }

    for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        area[row] = [];
        for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            area[row][col] = ' ';
        }
    } // функция для движения X по ячейкам в консоли

    area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = 'X';

    setChest(5); 
    
    render();
```

`

Comment: Создайте второе поле и разложите сундуки. При смене позиции проверяйте поле с сундуками. Либо когда у вас происходит движение, сначала посмотрите на знак в массиве, если * то консольте, а потом уже перетирайте данные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в ваши if проверку

```
if (direction === moveSet.up && heroPos.x !== 0) {
        if (area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] === '*') {
            console.log('Сундук собран')
        }
        area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = ' ';
        heroPos.x -= 1;
        area[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] = 'X';
    }
```

Хотя лучше всего, что бы не показывать пользователю где сундуки, создать отдельное поле area2, в него поместить ваши * и сверять
let area2 = [];

```
for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    area[row] = [];
    area2[row] = [];
    for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        area[row][col] = ' ';
        area2[row][col] = ' ';
    }
} // функция для движения X по ячейкам в консоли

function setChest(chests) {
    for (let value = 0; value < chests; value++) {
        area2[rndChest(rows)][rndChest(cols)] = '*';
    }
}

if (area2[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] === '*') {
            area2[heroPos.x][heroPos.y] === ' '
            console.log('Сундук собран')
        }
```

Comment: Единственное, наверное более правильнее проверять не текущее местоположение, а будущее, куда ваш супергерой шагает...